# Crystal Reports get all records relative to a field

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports, vb6

The task is simple but looks complicated for Crystal Reports

I have this table

```
ID GroupID PartyID .....
1  1       1
2  1       2
3  1       3
4  2       2
5  2       1
... so on
```

So for a `GroupID` there can be different party records

Now I want to get all group records of party # 1, it should return groups 1 and 2 both

And if I want records for party # 3, then it should only return group 1 records (IDs 1,2 and 3)

I have `PartyID` sent to Crystal Reports as a parameter.

What happens when I use this parameter to filer the results, is that I only get that particular party record. For e.g. if part id = 1 then I will get records ID=1 and 5 only, while I should get all records 1 to 5
And if party id = 3 is passed, I only get record ID=3, while I should get (or want to get) records ID=1,2 and 3

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I understand that there should be some kind of group matching involved in the record selection formula. But what should it be, I dont really understand. Can somebody help!

Comment: It looks like there is no way we can do that except for send the distinct group ids instead of sending the party id as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [self-join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177490%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to accomplish this.  Effectively you are using one copy of the table to identify the `GroupID` values associated with your `PartyID`, then using the second copy of the table to find all the rows with those `GroupID` values.

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.GroupID, Table1.PartyID
FROM Table Table1
    INNER JOIN Table Table2 ON Table1.GroupID = Table2.GroupID
WHERE Table2.PartyID = <<PartyID>>
```